# Why doesn't "while True" increments "i" continuously in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code such that the value of 'i' should increase until the outer while loop breaks (structure of the code shown in the image).

But, this doesn't increment the value of 'i', it is always being printed as '1'.

This is the structure of the code I have written:

```
while True:
  statement1
  statement2
  ...
  ...
  i=0
  i=i+1
  print(i)
  if some_condition=True:
    break;
```

what should I do if I want to increment the value of "i" continuously until the outer while loop breaks?

Comment: post a reproducible example please

Comment: please don't link to your code on another site.

Comment: and use a code block, not an image

Answer (score 2):

You always set i=0 in the while loop. Move i=0 before **while** statement.

```
i=0
while True:
  statement1
  statement2
  ...
  ...
  i=i+1
  print(i)
  if some_condition=True:
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `i=0` in each iteration. Put that `i=0` before your while-loop.